# Why the following function is called thrice

Tags: c

I had tried to debug but no luck I can't understand why the second printf() is call increment() thrice but the first one call twice as expected.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX(a, b) ( (a) > (b) ? (a) : (b) )

int increment(){
    static int i = 42;
    i += 5;
    printf("increment returns %d\n", i); // 47, 52, 57
    return i;
}

int main( int argc, char ** argv ) {
    int x = 50;
    // parameters compute from right to left side
    printf("max of %d and %d is %d\n",
                x, //3rd: 50
                increment(), //2nd: 52
                MAX(x, increment()) //1st: 50,47 -> 50
                );

    printf("max of %d and %d is %d\n",
                x, //3rd: 50
                increment(), //2nd: 62
                MAX(x, increment()) //1st: 50,57 -> 57
                );
    return 0;
}
```

The result

```
increment returns 47
increment returns 52
max of 50 and 52 is 50
increment returns 57
increment returns 62
increment returns 67
max of 50 and 67 is 62
```

Comment: What happens if you put the Max increment value in a different var ?

Comment: Please note that your code contains undefined behavior. Try to fix it, as it could lead to vicious error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because you tell it so:

```
MAX(x, increment())
```

evaluates to

```
( (x) > (increment()) ? (x) : (increment()) )
```

and if the condition is not fulfilled, the part after the `:` is evaluated and thus the function called again.

Answer (score 4):

Because macro: `MAX(x, increment())` expands as:

```
( (x) > (increment()) ? (x) : (increment()) )
```

Similarly next call of macro expands.

Variable `i` is static so initially initialized with `i = 42`, and its incremented value persists in different function calls.

below a sequence of function call shown with values of `i` returned by `increment()` function.

```
 increment();    i = 47, First call

   x      52       x     i       
( (50) > (52) ? (50) : (52) ) 
        Second        // ^ not called because condition is True 50 > 52
```

second time:

```
    increment();   i = 57, Third call

     x      i       x      i         
  ( (50) > (62) ? (50) : (67) ) 
          Forth          Fifth   // called because condition is False  50 > 62
```

This sequence is according to your output.

Important to note you may be different output with different compilers because the order of evaluation of function arguments are undefined of [Undefined behavior.](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#evaluation-order)

http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#macro

Answer (score 1):

This happens because your macro will expand as `( (x) > (increment()) ? (x) : (increment()) )`.

However, this is not the only problem, your code contains **undefined behaviour**. Parameters are not evaluated in a specified order.

Comment: I'm afraid there is no parameter passing in this program

Comment: @StefanoFalasca Well, I may be wrong, be aren't varargs evaluated like any other parameters?

Comment: where are the varargs?

Comment: @StefanoFalasca Call to `printf()` maybe?

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic example of side effects in macros. Your `max` macro examples out to this:

```
x > increment() ? x : increment()
```

Once the return value from increment() if bigger than `x` the ternary operator will call `increment()` twice, once to evaluate the condition and once to evaluate the false part (which is the second `increment()`).

In this case you're best best is to max  `max_int` function:

```
int max_int(int a, int b)
{
  return a > b ? a : b;
}
```

Calling this instead of `MAX` will ensure your arguments are only ever evaluated once.

Answer (score 0):

Use of macros is highly "dangerous": all sort of strange things can happen. For instance, in your case, if you call `MAX( f(), g() )` the function which gives you the greatest result gets called twice, the other one gets called just once. Since you are using `MAX(x, f())`, `f` gets called twice if and only if it gives a result which is greater than `x`.

In particular, the macro expands as

```
 ( (x) > (increment())? (x):(increment()) )
```

so that if the condition (testing which requires one evaluation of `increment()`, `increment()` gets executed in order to produce the result.

Comment: "Use of macros is highly deprecated" Not that I know of. While there may happen strange things you should be aware of, they are used widely for a variety of things.

Answer (score 0):

( (a) > (b) ? (a) : (b) )

In this statement, if b stands for a function, it will be called just once if (a > b) is true, but twice if (a > b) is false: one to give parameters for the comparison(b in "(a) > (b)"), the other to return a value for the whole statement(b in the latter part of the macro).

In your case, there's an extra call of "b"(increment) to provide the second integer parameter in each test.

Altogether, its twice and thrice.